# Listener to check for first character in autocompleteTextview

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview

I have one **AutocompleteTextview** and a delete **Button** in a framelayout.I can enter text and able to see my suggestion list and delete button to clear all text at once.

**What I want :** is as soon as I enter my first character delete button should visible and and when I press delete button visibility should gone.I can control the visibility of a button but not sure how to check for first entered character.Please help me on this.This is what I have in my xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/srcsutocomplete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="My Location "
        android:dropDownSelector="#a0b4f0">

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/clearSourceBtn"      
      android:layout_width="30dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/ic_navigation_cancel" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the delete button visible as soon as a character is typed:

Use a `TextWatcher` and its methods. I assume that in your case `onTextChanged` will do the trick. You can add it by calling `YourView.addTextChangedListener(watch)`

```
TextWatcher watch = new TextWatcher(){

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    /* This method is called to notify you that, 
     somewhere within s, the text has been changed. */
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int count, int start,
      int after) {
    /* This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count 
       characters beginning at start are about to be replaced by new 
       text with length after. */
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    /* This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters
       beginning at start have just replaced old text that had length before. */
        if(s.length() > 0) {
            DeleteButton.setVisibility(true);
        }
    }
}};
```

To make the delete button invisible as soon as it's pressed:

```
DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener({
    void onClick (View v) {
        DeleteButton.setVisibility(false);
    }
};
```